# submit with php array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My objective with this code is when an user click in edit button,  is sent this `all=<?php echo $arr; ?>` to the page `edit.php` .

This code simply does nothing (no ajax call in firebug).

```
<?php 
$arr = array("one", "two", "three")
?>
    <div id="content">
    <input class="edit" type="submit" value="Edit" /> 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".edit").submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "edit.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "html",
                data: "<?php echo json_encode( $arr ); ?>",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#ad').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Umm you know you can't just 'echo' an array right? It will have to be either json or serialized in order to be sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** As @MilanJaric showed, you do need to operate on the `click` of the submit button. In addition, however, you should prevent the default action of the click as well. **End Edit**

You need to echo the data json_encoded and wrapped in quotes:

```
<div id="content">
  <input class="edit" type="submit" value="Edit" /> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $( function()
  {
    $( '.edit' ).click( function( e )
    {
      $.ajax( {
        url: 'edit.php;,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: '<?php echo json_encode( $arr ); ?>',
        /* It's hard to tell based on your code, but if you wanted a var at the server named "all" use this instead of the above line:
        data: {
          all: '<?php echo json_encode( $arr ); ?>'
        },
        */
        success: function( data )
        {
          $( '#ad' ).html( data );
        }
      } );

      e.preventDefault();
    } );
  } );
</script>
```

IMO, however, it gets real ugly to echo PHP inside your JS especially if you have to do a lot of it, so when the need arises, I use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to inject PHP data into the code as a JS var. This allows me to isolate all PHP echoing within the parens of the invocation of the IIFE:

```
<?php 
  $arr = array("one", "two", "three")
?>

<div id="content">
  <input class="edit" type="submit" value="Edit" /> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  ( function( arr )
  {
    $( function()
    {
      $( '.edit' ).click( function( e )
      {
        $.ajax( {
          url: 'edit.php;,
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'html',
          data: arr,
          /* It's hard to tell based on your code, but if you wanted a var at the server named "all" use this instead of the above line:
          data: {
            all: arr
          },
          */
          success: function( data )
          {
            $( '#ad' ).html( data );
          }
        } );

        e.preventDefault();
      } );
    } );
  }(
    '<?php echo json_encode( $arr ); ?>'
  ) );
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what the other folks pointed out regarding the need to `json_encode()` your `$arr`, the [jQuery documentation for .submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) points out the following:

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to
>   submit a form. It can only be attached to <form> elements.

So I believe the reason the AJAX isn't even being submitted is that your `<input>` element is not within a `<form>` element.  Try the following:

```
<?php 
$arr = array("one", "two", "three");
?>

<form id="content">
<input class="edit" type="submit" value="Edit" /> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".edit").submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "edit.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            data: "all=<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ad').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript `submit` event only occurs on a `<form>` not on individual `<input>`s.

You need the following HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <form id="whatever">
        <input class="edit" type="submit" value="Edit" /> 
    </form>
</div>
```

And in the JavaScript change:

```
$( '.edit' ).submit( function()
```

to

```
$( '#whatever' ).submit( function()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".edit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "edit.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            data: "all=<?php echo $arr; ?>",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ad').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: `echo $arr` will return `Array`. How is your code supposed to work?

Comment: @MilanJaric  All you did was copy the JS from the OP...how is that an answer?

Comment: the problem is .click. He is right. Obviously i will change  `data: "all=<?php echo $arr; ?>"`, to  ` <?php echo json_encode( $arr ); ?>
`

Comment: @JAAulde if you read careful question you can see that firebug didn't log any ajax call, means not executed. and thanks for negative vote!

Comment: @user455318 It is _part_ of the answer to your question. That said, the biggest issue in your code was the attempted direct echo of the PHP array into JS

Comment: @MilanJaric I apologize for missing the fact that you changed `submit` to `click` and did not, in fact, directly copy. That said, you did not prevent default on the click event, and left the `echo`'ed PHP array in place, so I think the -1 is fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use a json_encode to encode php array to json string
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing an Array, which will make PHP echo something like Array(), in stead of the true values.
Try var_dump($arr); to dump the array, and eventually try serialising the array, easier to retrieve its state later.
If the ajax call does work with static data, then this is where you should start looking.